# email users using array from foreach

Tags: php

I asked a previous question about this but it has changed since, I would like to create an array from the db query `'$to'` and use it in the `email_to_user()` function. This will hopefully email all users from the `$entry->dept` array.

When `$entry->dept = 1` this works and emails the user from `department #1`
when `$entry->dept = 1,30` the email function fails.

```
$divisions = explode(",", $entry->dept);

foreach($divisions as $division) {
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    $to = get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id);
}

if (email_to_user($to, $from, $subject, $body)){
     redirect('thanks.php');
     die;
} 
else {}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sending mails with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
function email_to_user($toemail, $from, $subject, $body){
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $from\r\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $result = true;
    foreach ($toemail as $email){
         if (!mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers)){
            $result=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: lol, i already know this. $to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com'; so how do i implement with my code?

Comment: its either the fact that its been a long day or the fact im plain not understanding. How do i fit this in with my code?

Comment: Just add this function before your code. Also, if it is still not working, maybe your system does not have sendmail configured. In that case consider using something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

Comment: thanks for your help, i have sendmail setup on the server and i already have the email_to_user() function defined. The code i have works great for one user, its just when i have 2 or more users defined in the $entry->dept array.