# email using array from foreach

Tags: php

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$divisions = explode(",", $entry->dept);

foreach($divisions as $division) {
     $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);

$useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);

    $to = get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id);  }

if (email_to_user($to, $from, $subject, $body)){    

redirect('thanks.php'); die;

}  else {

} ?>
```

Works great when emailing one person but when you try to email a few in the array it does not work.

Comment: The posted code basically says: loop through all divisions, and find all to addresses. Overwrite the 2 variables each time, and then send one email. The to value will have the very last iteration.

Comment: when one division is in the array it emails, when 2 divisions are in the array it does not email and does whatever is in the else at the bottom of the code

Comment: how do i get $to = get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id); to append $to in an array foreach?

Comment: @Matthew: Please don't open a new question with every new try you shuffle to achieve the same: possible duplicate of [email users using array from foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996175/email-users-using-array-from-foreach)

Comment: @hakre: sorry, i did not want to just edit the previous question.  I cvould not find a way to add another post to my question and the comment bit is bad for putting code in. and as i have put in the new criteria to the question i am getting better responses for what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you send the email outside the loop and above that, overwrite the data with each iteration of the loop.

What you probably are attempting to do:

```
<?php

$statuses = array();

$divisions = explode(",", $entry->dept);

foreach($divisions as $division) {
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    $to = get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id);
    $email_status = email_to_user($to, $from, $subject, $body);
    $statuses [] = array('email_to' => $to, 'success' => $email_status);
}

foreach($statuses as $status) {
   if(!$status['success']) {
     //something went wrong with this email, handle it
   }
}
redirect('thanks.php'); die;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to send an email everyone in your list, try this:

```
foreach($divisions as $division) 
{
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    $to = get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id);  
    email_to_user($to, $from, $subject, $body);
}
```

Perhaps you want to make it efficient and BCC the entire list? Make a new function to send an email with the BCC, rather than the TO. Supply it with a comma/semicolon valued string of all your addressees.

```
foreach($divisions as $division) 
{
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    $bcc .= get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id).";";       
}
send_email_bcc($bcc, $from, $subject, $body);
```

For concatenating a string in a loop use `.=` operator:

```
 $myVariable .= get_record('user', 'id', $useremail->id).";";
```

I've include a semi-colon as a separator at the end of each email address above.